# Docker compose command fails but doesn't trigger jenkins failure

Tags: docker, jenkins

I have a jenkins pipeline with docker for node/npm builds. If they fail, Jenkins still shows the build as succeeding. How do I make it detect the failure?

My jenkins file looks like this:

```
    stage('Deploy Staging') {
      when {
        branch 'staging'
      }
      steps {
        sh 'ssh root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xx "cd project; git checkout staging; git fetch origin staging; git reset --hard origin/staging; COMPOSE_FILE=build/staging/docker-compose.yml make build-all; COMPOSE_FILE=build/staging/docker-compose.yml make up;"'
        discordSend description: "Staging pipeline build status: ${currentBuild.currentResult}", link: env.BUILD_URL, result: currentBuild.currentResult, title: JOB_NAME, webhookURL: 'url'
      }
    }
```

Comment: have you tried to use the try-catch block to catch any exceptions thrown during the build and signal a failure using the currentBuild.setResult() method?

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution that is not specific to npm build failures, but you could consider using the [Log Parser](https://plugins.jenkins.io/log-parser/) plugin. This plugin allows you to set console parsing rules which takes the console output of the log and scans it for parsing rules that you specify. You can then make the build fail/pass/warn when text that matches these rules are encountered.

So in your case you could make a rule that matches to your npm build failure message and force the build to fail when the build failure occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to make sure the `make build-all` had an explicit `|| exit 1` at the end for this to exit correctly.